# MongoDB - Exclude an inner array but include it's count

Tags: arrays, mongodb, include, count

I have a table called `devicesegments`, each row of which contains a large array called devices. Owing to the size of the device array, I've been asked not to include it in my query for a page that lists all `devicesegment`s, but only include their count. Is this possible? 
What I was doing before : 
A simple `db.devicesegments.find()`

What I'm doing now : 
`db.devicesegments.find({}, { devices : 0 })`

What I want to achieve : 
`db.devicesegments.find({}, { devices : 0, devices.length : 1 })`

Something like a `COUNT(devices) AS device_count`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ashkay, there's no way to do this with Mongo currently. As @rompetroll says, your application should keep a "count" field on each document, and carefully $inc it whenever you change the number of entries in the array. Then when you query for the document, exclude the array like:

```
db.collection.find({}, {devices:0})
```

If you're willing to run MongoDB 2.1, which is a development release, the aggregation framework provides a means to calculate the array size within a query:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no way to currently do this, without including a new `device_count` in my table, the temporary fix that I applied was to fetch all the data from the database, along with the `devices` array, and for each row, add a field for `devices.length` and then remove the `devices` array before sending the data across.